# PHP Warning: Module already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, configuration, centos7, ini, intl

On Mac OSX Mavericks using homebrew php55 whenever I run a a php command I get the following error message (everything runs fine it's just annoying)

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I ran

```
php --ini
```

and the output was

```
php --ini
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mongo.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-uuid.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

Checked in the php.ini file and the only place intl is loaded is at the top and it's commented out. The other files contents look something like:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.23/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so"
```

where the contents after the last slash is the extension.

I'm not sure where else to look.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Check /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-intl.ini and /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini Most likely it's there more than once.

Comment: Try to enable the intl extension at the php.ini file and remove (with back up) the file ext-intl.ini

Comment: I solved this problem by checking each of the `.ini` file under the `conf.d` directory, and found there's two same line `extension=imagick.so` in the `imagick.ini`, and I removed one of them it works fine

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I think you have loaded [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) probably twice in [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

1. check the `php.ini`, that not have set `xdebug.so` for the values `extension=` and `zend_extension=`.
2. Check also `/etc/php5/apache2` and `/etc/php5/cli/`. You should not load in each `php.ini` in these directories the extension `xdebug.so`. Only one file, `php.ini` should load it.

   Note: Inside the path is the string `/etc/php5`. The 5 is the version of PHP. So if you use another version, you always get a different path, like `php7`.

Comment: Hey , I can't find xdebug in my `cli/php.ini` and still its showing me these errors.
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2 (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/gd2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: on my one (mac, php installed using brew), when I install xhprof using pecl, it automatically added `extension='xhprof.so'` at the top of `php.ini file`. and then there was another file at `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-xhprof.ini`. commenting out the line on `php.ini` removed the warning.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue on mac i.e. `Warning: Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`.
Here's how I solved it.

- Locate the **folder** `conf.d`, mine was in the directory
  `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d`.
- In this folder, there's a **file** called `ext-pdo_pgsql.ini`.
- Type `sudo nano ext-pdo_pgsql.ini` to edit it.
- There should be a line `extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so"`. Comment it
  out by adding semi-colon to the beginning of the line i.e.
  `;extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so"`.
- Save the file. (I usually run **control + O**, **control + M**).
- Exit the file (**control + X**).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me for 'mongodb' issue in ubuntu 18.04. I found similar file for mongodb in etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d

Comment: worked as well for me with pgsql.ini

Answer (score 19):

To fix this problem, you must edit your php.ini (or extensions.ini) file and comment-out the extensions that are already compiled-in. For example, after editing, your ini file may look like the lines below:

```
;extension=pcre.so
;extension=spl.so
```

Source: http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Comment: This is correct. in my case, i had mysqli extension called twice so i commented out one of them and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 12):

You should have a */etc/php2/conf.d* directory (At least on Ubuntu I do) containing a bunch of .ini files which all get loaded when php runs. These files can contain duplicate settings that conflict with settings in `php.ini`. In my PHP installation I notice a file `conf.d/20-intl.ini` with an `extension=intl.so` setting. I bet that's your conflict.

Comment: You can use ```php --ini | grep intl``` to find extra ini files for the module and check the php.ini file if it has ```extension=intl.so```. As a solution, you can comment the later in the php.ini or delete the file(s) show in the first command.

Answer (score 9):

solved by commenting extension=curl

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had uncoment the ;extension=php_curl.so in php.ini, but Ubuntu was already calling this extension somewhere else.

To find this "somewhere else", on php.ini will informe. On my case:
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini was the path.

So now we edit this file (terminal):

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.1/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini
```

Comment the ;extension=php_curl.so

Save file and restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
For issue related to code igniter project upload,
go to the base directory index.php and add this code:

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'local_server_name') {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')){
    switch (ENVIRONMENT){
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}


    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

For shared hosting, in cPanel I unchecked the Module in question under "Select PHP Version" > "Extensions" and the error disappeared for PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading from **Fedora Server 24 *(PHP 5)* to 25** ***(PHP 7)***. After investigation, I found that `/etc/php.d/` had two different `.ini` files loading `extension=geoip.so`.

Previous version of distros had this file named `50-geoip.ini` but the recent was changed to `40-geoip.ini`, and I suspect that in the version-upgrade process the old hasn't been removed, while the new one has been created.

That was the actual case of the issue. After removing stray `50-geoip.ini` from `/etc/php.d/` and restarting `httpd` it just worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the 20-mongo.ini file in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by printing the PHP configuration and searching by xml.ini. Notice in the following output how xml is loaded twice (first as 20-xml.ini and then as xml.ini):

```
$ php -i | grep xml
/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xml.ini
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
libxml Version => 2.9.1
libxml
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text /|application/xhtml\+xml)
xml
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1
xmlreader
xmlwriter
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two "php_intl.dll" files inside php.ini file on 872 and 968 number lines. if **php warning module 'intl' already loaded in unknown on line 0** this message is focused on your CLI. Then you should have to remove the semiclone prefixes on line 872. I expect this will done.....

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record as it might help others who are on shared hosting (cPanel).

I had error on shared hosting php7.2: 
Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

In the beginning hosting provider said it was my bad configuration (running Yii2.16). But after I showed them, that all Internet related this issue to server configuration -they started to listen to me. After I proved, that there was no error on php7.1 they started to search for the error.

As they told to me - the error was due to configuration in PERL modules or PEAR package, but they did not told me the real issue.

So, if you are on shared hosting - talk to you provider and experiment with PHP versions (if you can change them).

Answer (score 0):

Comment out these two lines in `php.ini`

```
;extension=imagick.so
;extension="ixed.5.6.lin"
```

it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, I fix this by comment like this

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `php --ini` and notice file path on `Loaded Configuration File`.
Then run command like `cat -n /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini | grep intl` to find if the extension is commented or not.
Then update loaded configuration file by commenting line by adding `;` such as `;extension=intl`

This can happen when you install `php-intl` package and also enable the same extension on `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on shared hosting, just apply the default php settings. Cpanel overrides php settings to default.

Comment: This is likely to be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I am using WAMP in Windows 10 with PHP 7.2.10. I was able to solve it through commenting the line `extension=ftp` in php.ini inside wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10 .

I am unsure but my guess why this happens is that my php.ini inside wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin already loads this module.

Be sure to restart all services of WAMP after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing **php.ini** file from **extension=grpc** commenting like this **;extension=grpc**

Answer (score 0):

If you install PHP using MacPorts (I know, call me a dinosaur), it doesn't create a php.ini file. Instead it creates a bunch of ini files in `/opt/local/var/db/php82` (or whatever version you installed) which are also read. If you create a php.ini yourself, and assume you have to add the extensions, as any sane person would, you will see this error.

This is what my installation looks like.

```
% ll /opt/local/var/db/php82 
total 144
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  admin  672 Nov 17 07:22 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  160 Nov 16 19:23 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  231 Nov 17 06:52 curl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  227 Nov 17 06:51 gd.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  237 Nov 17 06:53 gettext.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  233 Nov 17 06:53 iconv.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  231 Nov 17 06:56 imap.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  231 Nov 17 06:52 intl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  239 Nov 17 06:55 mbstring.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  235 Nov 17 06:57 mcrypt.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  257 Nov 17 06:58 mysql.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  300 Nov 17 07:02 opcache.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  237 Nov 17 06:58 openssl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  237 Nov 17 06:58 sockets.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  260 Nov 17 07:03 sqlite.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  231 Nov 17 07:02 tidy.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  298 Nov 17 07:22 xdebug.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  235 Nov 17 06:57 xmlrpc.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  229 Nov 17 07:02 xsl.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  229 Nov 17 07:00 zip.ini

cat /opt/local/var/db/php82/mysql.ini
; Do not edit this file; it is automatically generated by MacPorts. Any changes
; you make will be lost if you upgrade, uninstall or deactivate php82-mysql.
; To configure php82, edit /opt/local/etc/php82/php.ini.
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

There is no `/opt/local/etc/php82/php.ini`. Instead there are two files: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`, which you can use as templates for your php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, the problem was that the extension intl was duplicated.

You can check in file C:/xampp/php/php.ini and find "intl". In my case extension=intl is already present and I scrolled again and found a second intl "extension=php_intl.dll".

The extension must one to execution can't execution extension intl again. This will show error like this "Module 'intl' already loaded".

I fixed it by commenting out `extension=php_intl.dll` using "`;`" like this `;extension=php_intl.dll`. and restarted the apache service.