# Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have successfully installed PHP intl extension, I have noticed that I should enable the intl extension in php.ini file by removing semicolon and when I did that warning appears told me that the extension already loaded so I have edit the php.ini again and re-add the semicolon for "extension=intl.so" to be like this ";extension=intl.so"
how ever the same error from CakePHP still appear, I don't know if the extension is really loaded or not.

Note: I'm using Mac OS X version 10.12.4
PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: uncomment again and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0

Comment: I'm running php 7.1.x on mac OSX. Hope this link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system/47560288#47560288

Comment: after applying changes in php.ini file you have to restart your server, have you follow this step??

Comment: Are you editing the right `php.ini` file? Sometimes the server uses a different PHP package than the desktop.