# mongodb already loaded error php core warning occur

Tags: php, mongodb

sometimes, mongodb doesn't fetch any data and return this error message

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>  
<p>Severity: Core Warning</p>
<p>Message: Module 'mongo' already loaded</p>
<p>Filename: Unknown</p>
<p>Line Number: 0</p>


<p>Backtrace:</p>
```

UI also affected because of this error. can i make change anything in library file?. Any solution appreciated.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0), please

Answer (score 0):

it occured when you give wrong address of controller and class in the controller please set path in the routs.php. than define in the controller.after that error will not occure in your server.