# Php Module already exist

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

Hey guys i have a little error i am trying to integrate mongoDB in my symfony project :) But when i do php bin/console i have this error :

> PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   Could not open input file: bin/console

I think that happens when i add `mongodb.so` in my php.ini.

I think if i resolve this it will resolve my error with mongoDB that i explain there : [link to other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809377/how-to-push-mongodb-entity)

Thx for all that will try to help :p

nb : i have composer version 1.6.5 and php 7

Update : I did composer update and that what it returns now when i do php bin/console :

> PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>   Symfony 3.4.14 (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)
>
> Usage:
>    command [options] [arguments]
>
> Options:
>    -h, --help            Display this help message
>    -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
>    -V, --version         Display this application version
>        --ansi            Force ANSI output
>    -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
>    -e, --env=ENV         The Environment name. [default: "dev"]
>        --no-debug        Switches off debug mode.
>    -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal > output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
>
> Available commands:
>    about                                   Displays information about the > current project ....

I got that when i do php --ini :

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/50-mongodb.ini
```

Comment: See if this solution could work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0

Comment: not working i don't have any zend_extension or extension for imagick.so .. .

Comment: i search before post this and nothing resolved my problem only thing that i didn't do is to check if i have an other php.ini loaded but don't know how to do it in fedora 28 .. ?

Comment: i did : php -i|grep 'Loaded Configuration File' but only one php.ini file is loaded ... and it's the good one ...

Comment: Try `php -i|grep ini`

Comment: Everything points to configuration files though... it seems it's a generic message for modules loaded in two ini files, now the mission is to find them. https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/solved-php-warning-module-xx-already-loaded.44761/

Also, did you try uninstalling the php extension?

Comment: You can use the command `php --ini` to get a list of all ini configuration files that are processed by PHP. You will need to check of all them and make sure that the extension is loaded in only one of the files.

Comment: php -i|grep ini i got only one php.ini