# How can i make a controller for laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i did some controller befor but now im trying to create no one but the command dosn't work[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1x3m.png.)

Comment: check this answer, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0

Comment: I think you have loaded **mysqli** probably twice in **php.ini**. You should not load in each **php.ini** in this directories the extension `mysqli`.  Only one file **php.ini** should load it.

Comment: It seems to me that your application is not configured properly.
Would mind answering a few of questions? 1 - is this a new installation of Laravel?
2 - how was the installation done?
3 - did you change any configuration related to the app namespace?

Comment: how can i set the php ini file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please run this two commands:

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
```